# int variable usage in Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I've an xml element that takes in a number. It's optional. I created the JAXB POJO classes and the same tag is mapped to an int variable in Java. Now, as the xml element is optional, user may not set it at all, which would set the corresponding java variable to 0.
  In some cases the user may set it and send in 0. Again, the java variable would be set to 0.
I was wondering whether there is a way to differentiate these two scenarios programmatically.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

For an XML element to be optional it would have to have the `minOccurs="0"` attribute set on it.

```
<xs:element name="foo" type="int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The JAXB would have created a property of type `Integer` to match your use case.

### Long Answer

**XML Schema**

The complex type `foo` has two elements of type `int`.  One is required and the other is optional (`minOccurs="1"`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="foo">
       <sequence>
           <element name="required" type="int"/>
           <element name="optional" type="int" minOccurs="0"/>
       </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**Generated Model**

In the generated model we see that a property of type `int` was generated for the required property, and a property of type `Integer` was generated for the optional property.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"required","optional"})
public class Foo {

    protected int required;
    protected Integer optional;

    public int getRequired() {
        return required;
    }

    public void setRequired(int value) {
        this.required = value;
    }

    public Integer getOptional() {
        return optional;
    }

    public void setOptional(Integer value) {
        this.optional = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry Blaise. I think I was not clear enough. First, I am talking about a single optional tag. The user may set it or may not. In case it isn't, it will be set to 0 in java variable. In case the user sets it to 0, it is 0. What I wanna know is how to differentiate the two while parsing the xml. For example, if the user does not set, I won't raise an alarm, even though the value is 0. In case it is set to 0 explicitly, I wanna raise an alarm. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: @Aceghn - I think I understand your question.  You can make the property (or generate as I've shown above) an Integer, then it will be null when it is not present in the document and have a value otherwise.  In Java you can treat an `Integer` the same as an `int`.  Just be sure to do a null check on it first.